# Auto logging using C#

Tags: c#, .net, logging, event-handling

I have a class and i want to log every action performed in a class.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             Log.Info("button clicked");
        }
    }
```

e.g : if some one creates instance of a class so i could log it on file. Same if some variable is set or function is called i want to log it automatically. There are few ways i can log using `log4net` by using `Log.Info()` method inside my class or inside every method that i want to log. For this purpose i have to put this code everywhere. Instead of that i want to capture events dynamically without writing `Log.Info()` everywhere .

Comment: Do you want to do it in the context of Windows forms only or in general? With Windows forms you could perhaps intercept the messages at a lower level and do some logging based on that. In general, the only way I can think of doing this is using a DynamicObject and Reflection as wrapper. Not type safe and not exactly elegant either. Maybe someone knows a better way?

Comment: Use AOP framework like [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) (free version should be enough).

Comment: This would be a good read http://www.dotnetcurry.com/patterns-practices/1305/aspect-oriented-programming-aop-csharp-using-solid , it explains how to develop your own Aspect oriented approach to logging using primarily a decorator pattern.